Headset is wrong? Big gap between fork and headtube
I need some help assembling the frame I bought into a bike. I am a little bit ouf of depth with my current knowledge (which is based on googling some headset standards articles).
I bought a Scott Speedster Gravel 10 frame and fork. Due to the painting I believe it's the 2019 model in size XL (see gravelbikedatabase or 99spokes).
My current (main) problem has to do with the headset. Since, I didn't see an angled area for direct installation of bearings and I didn't see outer bearing cups on the online pictures of the bike I saw, I assumed I am going to need a Zero Stack headset. I did measure 44mm and 49,5mm for the upper and lower inside diameter of the frame. So, I bought a ZS44/ZS49 headset. But when putting in the fork (which seems to have an integrated crown race), it looks like this. So, something is wrong. I have added some pictures of how it looks and another online picture of how it's probably supposed to look like. I am also confused about the online picture as there seems to be something installed on top of the integrated crown race?
Additional but unrelated questions:

If I understood it correctly, there is always a centering sleeve (other name for compression ring?) above the upper bearing to contacting it? A centering sleeve is also not damaging to a carbon fork?

The referenced websites state that the bike was shipped with Shimano Ultegra Road groupsets. I do have some parts of a Shimano Sora group lying around and I was just wondering whether this would fit the frame (regarding chainline and other stuff I don't know a lot about)? I guess this should work since it's also a Road groupset with similar measurements?


Thanks a lot for your help.
Edit:
I did measure the fork and at the top it has an outer diameter of 28.8mm, at the bottom just above the integrated crown race it's 29.9mm and at the bottom of the integrated crown race it's roughly 44.5mm. So, the fork is not really a 1¹/⁸ to 1¹/⁴ fork. So, this actually is a straight 1¹/⁸" fork? This seems contradictory to the linked entries from 99spokes/gravelbikedatabase. The fork at least is painted like on the pictures so I guess there wasn't a mixup of forks (which could theoretically be possible since I bought this frame second hand).
The headset I currently have is a ZS44/28.6 ZS49/30, which seems to be fit to the 1¹/⁸ fork but the integrated crown race is just so high that this big gap is created. One comment suggest using an ec49/40 lower headset, which I believe might work. However, on the online picture (last pic linked here) of the bike doesn't seem to show an external cup. In summary, I am still confused.
Edit 2:
Measurements of frame and fork:

Upper headtube inner diameter: 44mm
Lower headtube inner diameter: 49.5mm
top of steering column outer diameter: 28.8mm
steering column outer diamter just above the integrated crown race: 29.9mm
outer diamter at the bottom of the integrated crown race: 44.5mm
height of the integrated crown race: approx. 10mm

Headset (I currently have) (says it's a ZS44/28.6 ZS49/30 headset):

Upper bearing cup inner diameter: 41.3mm
Lower bearing cup inner diameter: 41.2mm
Bearing 1 (outer diameter: 41.1mm, inner diameter: 30.1mm)
Bearing 2 (outer diameter: 41.0mm, inner diameter: 30.1mm)

Pictures:

frame headtube
fork
fork with bearing
fork installed
online picture

I think you need an external cup (ec4*) lower headset for your tapered - style fork steerer. The bearing on it is clearly too small in internal diameter.

Hmm, okay. I saw some EC49/40 lower cups online which might be the right size. I am just confused because on the online pictures of the bike (last pic I linked) you don't see an external cup, right?

Now, I also saw some ZS49/40 lower heatset cups. But both for ZS49/40 and EC49/40, it usually stated that this was for a 1¹/² inch (tapered) fork, which mine is not. So, I not sure whether in that case 1. the gap would be better (I mean it will be smaller but still probably doesn't perfectly fit so that water and stuff can still penetrate) and 2. it's actually safe and working as the fork diameter would be wrong

but your frame doesn't look like the photo you supplied.

Your frame, i go further, is clearly different to your example image. and not just in colour.

@Noise My bad. Thanks for your observation. I did have a closer look again and apparently (with the frame lying on the floor) I managed to try to put in the fork the wrong way in the headtube (i.e. from above). Nonetheless, this actually doesn't really change my observations. I will update the picture with a new one.

On this forum, no one (i include myself) should be ruled out as an idiot. Please try each bearing in turn on the fork and see if they sit differently. Do not assume they are the same. Your measurements are very vague.

@Noise I am not sure if I fully understand your comment. In the second Edit, I added more measurements and in particular of the bearings which are basically the same.

Don't worry. You may need to go to Scott to fix this properly (buy the headset from them). Or use a different fork.

You need the ID of the lower bearing to be ca. 44mm on this fork, according to your measurements.

Okay, I guess my best option is to email Scott.

On your 99 Spokes link above the fork is listed as having a tapered carbon steer tube that is 1⅛" top and 1¼" at the bottom. That doesn't help your problem since the bearing appears too small for the crown race.  Regarding your headset sizing: it does appear to use a ZS style headset (your reference links above use the term, "integrated steel cup" describing the headset. That term is a bit strange, but the mention of a steel cup makes me lean toward a ZS.
Regarding the size, you'll need to determine what the second numbers listed after the initial "ZS44/?? | ZS49/??"  The numbers behind the top 44 should be 28.6 (1⅛" in mm's) and 32 (whole number in mm's closest to 1¼"). These represent internal diameter of the bearings. Unfortunately, I don't see a ZS style headset for 1¼.  Is it possible the lower headtube is equipped to accept an integrated bearing (IS).  See this Park Tool headset reference table for the 1¼" options.  I still don't get why your bearing for the ZS49 appears too small unless you've transposed the bearings and that is the upper 1⅛" one you're trying to use. A ZS49/40 would be for the 1½" tapered fork.
The centering sleeve will need to be used. Some are plastic which may be better on the carbon fiber steer tube, but an aluminum alloy should be ok as the pressure should be spread out around the circumference of the steer tube.  Note that you cannot use a star-fangled nut in the carbon steer tube. You'll have to get an expanding nut designed for carbon steerer use. It should be located in the headtube where the clamping force of the stem. This creates even and opposing pressure on the steer tube so there's no chance of damage.
The Shimano Sora road group is 9 speed in the rear, comes in either a 2x or 3x front chain wheel. Fit on your bike should be the same as the Ultegra, except the cassette will be overall narrower and depending on your rear wheel hub (the HG Freehub body specifically), you may have to put on a spacer or two before the 9 speed cassette goes on. Your Sora parts should be the latest, Hollowtech2 style (24mm spindle attached to the drive side crank).  In addition, this bike is likely only set up for disc brakes.  This requires the STI (Shifter/brake lever combo) to be hydraulic brake capable.

Thank you for your answer. I did measure the fork to have an outer diameter of 28.8mm at the top, 29.9 mm just above the crown race and roughly 44.5 mm at the bottom of the integrated crown race. So, the fork doesn't really taper to 1 ¹/⁴"? Which is confusing. Now the cups are installed so it can't really see clearly but I am pretty sure that I inspected it before and there was no angled surface for a direct installation of a bearing. Okay, so I guess the metal centering sleeve will be fine. Just a question regarding your last sentence: Mechanical disc brakes should also be good, right?

I forgot to mention: The top and bottom bearings are actually the same size.

Check if you actually received correct bearings.

What exactly do you mean by that? I measured outer and inner diameter of both bearings and they are almost the same (1 or 2mm difference) .

Although this answer certainly has been useful, I still don't know how to proceed with the lower headset issue.

You've somehow been provided and incorrect lower headset. The bearing at least, since apparently the cup inserted without notable problems.  The crown race dimension is confusing as well since it measures 1¾". A tapered steer tube that is 1½" at the crown race gets a 40mm bearing. For headtube requiring a ZS headset it would be ZS49/40. There are no headsets for 1.75" diameter crown races. IDK what's going on.

Mechanical disc brakes use a long lever pull the same as rim V-brakes (aka linear pull brakes).  A road bike mechanical brake lever, is set up for use with cantilever brakes, and pulls about 20mm of cable versus the required 30mm of cable required by a V-brake (and therefore, a mechanical disc brake, since they're designed to use the long pull of a V-brake lever).  In addition to the cable pull length is the differing mechanical advantages of an STI (road bike lever) and a V-brake lever.  If you were to get 30mm of cable pull from the STI, the overload in mechanical advantage makes problems

@Jeff Yes, I am also confused. I just wanted to clarify that the crown race diameters I mentioned are outside diameters and not crown race inner diameters which get mentioned much more e.g. in the Parktool article you linked. Of course with an integrated crown race that's the only thing I can measure. Also what I don't understand is why this (or all?) integrated crown race seems so tall and has such a range in outer diameter when standard crown races are usually smaller and shallower.

@Jeff I don't fully understand your conclusion. You're saying road STI's with meachanical disc brakes would put more (too much) stress on the frame?

Essentially a road lever would reach the handlebar before adequate brake force could be applied by the calipers

But there are a lot of road bike builds with mechanical disc brakes. So how does this fit together?

@tor Road shifters/brake levers require road-specific mechanical disc brakes. Those have the same cable pull as cyclocross cantilever brakes or road rim brakes. For V-brakes or MTB mechanical disc brakes, you need MTB brake levers. I do not fully understand Jeff's comment. If he is implying you cannot use any mechanical disc brake, he is wrong. But you have to use the-road specific ones.

I didn't realize that mechanical disc brakes came in a road version.  In other words, that mechanical disc brakes used anything except a V-brake, long-pull design. Apologies.
